# How to show alert when click Showtodaybutton on 3 Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I need to alert something when I click the "today button".

**I tried :**

```
$(".glyphicon .glyphicon-screenshot").on('click',function(){
alert("Hey");});
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone can help me?

Comment: any error in `console log` ?

Comment: no error but no alert too

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colon after the closing parenthesis in the alert.

Comment: Oh sorry I my code I have semi colon but still problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet for jqueryui date-picker today click

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
 alert('clicked')
});
```

Comment: I use jquery 1.9.1 so live is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Use only one selector instead of two, that is, your code should be:

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function(){
alert("Hey");});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate classes using ',' like this

```
$(".glyphicon, .glyphicon-screenshot").on('click',function(){
alert("Hey")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please share your js,html file and the plugin you are working on ,the events should work perfectly if the class names are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing parenthesis in the alert will not cause any problem and the class name need not to be comma separated.

Comment: can you try this http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#showclose